# Where are the super weapons in each map?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In multiplayer, there are two types of super weapons: the mini-gun and the competition bow. These occupy the fourth weapon slot. They spawn in the map. Where do they typically spawn (in each map)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ## Beach
>
> #### Location #1
>
> The first one is located near the Survivors base. If you spawn, there are 3 exits. Left, middle and right. You can take the
>   left one and turn right. Or you can take the middle one and turn left.
>   There's a (very) small pillar right next to you where it spawns atop.
>
> Screenshots (far, near):
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400625399/F271E3B5D5AA3B2EA319B12ECBBF119EF3027256/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400626915/053261891179AC4E1AB015335247D9F5131B70D0/
>
> #### Location #2
>
> The second one is located closer to the Solarii base. There are wooden stepping stones in the middle of the air close to the
>   very tall tower. The spawnpoint is located on the last stepping point,
>   closest to Solarii base.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400631439/C199689F6AB893E06202FC3186C8D9E0C2D89B44/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400632248/2D896DBFEB06AD7B7A9EDE93BB2DF53BDBE76F8E/
>
> #### Location #3
>
> The third one is a hidden location. There's a big white/grey bunker in the map. It's closer to Solarii base, so if you
>   spawn as Solarii, face the Survivors base and look left. There's a big
>   bunker there. You'll have to climb to it through one of the 3 ways and
>   grab the superweapon within.
>
> Screenshots:
>
> - http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400615071/A91297976CB1EB438CD520839A38C6573F340B09/
>     http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400621651/16E239839FA16F8DAB414801405732E46F82C839/
> - http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400618774/B452B2FD2E9249C5C2955437409A37EEFE716BEF/
>     http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400621402/1F65A62DC46C2CCB612332A8E39B421F6D5E4600/
> - http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400619730/75C4C643F7230092E362A2D393532EE3C6217BA0/
>     http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686400622118/666BC6DB7786A391E6F12D4EEC8D539592EEEA15/
>
> #### Beach video
>
> I'll uphold the following rule in my videos:   Survivor's view first, then Solarii.
>   Loop from Location #1 to #3.
>
> #### Additional map notes
>
> The huge tower can be climbed all the way to the top! Many lightning rods in this map, they are instant-killing
>   traps, so beware!
>
> ---
>
> ## Shrine
>
> #### Location #1
>
> The first location is nearest to Survivor base. It's on the bridge on the far left right before the snare trap. There's a
>   little wooden altar thingy where most people hide behind. It spawns
>   right on the bridge there.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401525180/0965F82156C2C607AE3ADFF590ADF52B24496B05/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401528200/7E50AA34A2D7015F9A3221837203D85DCD9B7437/
>
> #### Location #2
>
> The second is nearest to Solarii base. There's a building with 2 rooms a first floor and a second floor. (a basement
>   too, but nevermind that) On the 2nd floor on the left room. There's 3
>   windows looking to Survivors base. Middle one will be open and left
>   and right one can be broken. The spawnpoint is on the right window on
>   a weird carpet thing.
>
> Screenshots:
>   - http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401535499/0E8AD645EAE85817449C4ABD7805DE1E79C75174/
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401536793/53374FD73281D6A3D94AC71357ACE00FFE9CAF19/
>
> - http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401537476/8BA4BE45039FD626175433D020559A68C0A50002/
>     http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401538724/E059C010A5CBC63C20837BF8A7BBE094D9672A34/
>
> #### Location #3
>
> The last spawnpoint is near the hill you can climb, on Solarii side. There's an explosive barrel on that ridge. It spawns
>   close-by.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401529639/173DEA2F1941202127068DA6AE9BFD6AC2C36A1B/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401534442/7B58A60BBEF0670053A7E942FBF7233A0F00E091/
>
> #### Additional map notes
>
> There's a basement with a spike trap and a mountain you can climb with your climbing axe.
>
> #### Shrine video
>
> I'll uphold the following rule in my videos:   Survivor's view first, then Solarii. 
>   Loop from Location #1  to #3.
>
> ---
>
> ## Chasm
>
> #### Location #1
>
> The first location is nearest to Survivor base. From survivor base, take the zip-line to the right and you'll land on a
>   small cabin/builing. Inside is the spawnpoint.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401869701/C0302F0B25CC3E8234551F8B5CC7BC873E6FB387/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401885062/08800D452B72A3F0A096AA2F8A2880305BE3F5A4/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886147/9A9E82D5A14F72009E9D79A137FA8A28664CC63F/
>
> #### Location #2
>
> The second spawnpoint is closer to the Solarii base. From their base, there's a zip-line on the left side that connects to
>   a 2 story tower on the left side of the big bell. The spawnpoint is on
>   the bottem floor.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401872541/6E54F139F1D741362F89454BB8F1336646C845C4/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401880672/5F176EA6943EA30A5B3927768E920681F017268C/
>
> Location #3
>   The last spawnpoint is somewhere in the middle. There's a
>   small hill going up/down from both other superweapon spawnpoints. It's
>   hidden in a corner inbetween.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886311/A984549A90EDA2CC282FA37E12BD33E5CBB2A36F/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886450/AE7BD6EAB451F776810C2961EE76E7FA6BEC22FA/
>
> #### Additional map notes
>
> The bell in this map can be rung in order to summon a sandstorm. Sandstorms limits visibility, but the first 10
>   seconds will grant whoever rung the bell, a survivor vision through
>   the storm. The lever is on the right side of the bell
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886578/42F1D43D61BB02977DC4F066DFEC6C15EF650B1C/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886744/A9CB432091F622F35F85CDD83223D73DB89ADA8C/
>   (dust-storm starts)
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686401886828/7E2F860244318A3371ECB055426CC88A256D262F/
>   (dusty, stormy)
>
> #### Chasm video
>
> I'll uphold the following rule in my videos:   Survivor's view first, then Solarii. 
>   Loop from Location #1 to #3.
>
> ---
>
> ## Underground
>
> #### Location #1
>
> The first one is pretty much right next to Survivors base. When you drop down in the middle exit. Turn right into the
>   doorway. It should be right there already. (the area for drop off for
>   medkits in rescue mode)
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402355876/EBFE396EC77E2C653B79ECC34388030BF109A7E7/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402357477/5F79CB3F1F16DE05C3FD3E40ABE7F1D5E72C9664/
>
> #### Location #2
>
> The second one is right next to the Solarii base. When you go through the middle exit from their spawn, turn right into
>   the doorway, it should be right there as well.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402368833/4EC8C81B6BD61D59117A985960C640C1F96CBF1F/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402375088/BE8BC7319C53B0784E72E88AFD1F1332D47F534B/
>
> #### Location #3
>
> The last one is in the middle. There's something floating on the water here. It's next to a stack of sandbags under the
>   bridge.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402353134/6C560F6710C7BEE54F71B3BDCD7A7E9250B6A3BF/
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402353315/3AC8EA37F43AA7EE7FD5F49DE53C46E991F19D39/
>
> #### Additional map notes
>
> When the round has been in progress for 4 minutes, the submarine will open and you can click the self-destruct
>   button. Doing so will set the remaining time on 2 minutes and the
>   whole level will start to fall apart. Random rocks that fall and kill
>   enemies(or teammates) will count as a kill for whoever pressed the
>   button.
>
> Another note: It doesn't matter what time it currently is in the game,
>   the self-destruct sequence will ALWAYS set it to 2 minutes left. So if
>   done properly, you can achieve a total roundtime of 6 minutes, or 12
>   minutes. (2 more than default)
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402361776/1CAB91D14560E624CBB91FBC9C4B12E18499A3E9/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402364670/0D1851592EE48E42223B04AE9E5D29A8160B6636/
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402377830/7247D2481A2A75FEF15ACE17747A796E98EC7FE5/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402383322/F7B7C9E34A40276433EB70B5C82C3B5F7131836E/
>
> #### Underground video
>
> I'll uphold the following rule in my videos:   Survivor's view first, then Solarii. 
>   Loop from Location #1 to #3.
>
> ---
>
> ## Monastery
>
> #### Location #1
>
> All 3 are in favour for Survivors, the first one is under the main path. Take the far right exit from Survivors base and
>   follow the path a little. There'll be a crossing and an explosive
>   barrel to your left. It's hidden behind this barrel.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402612306/2E2CF5B1A91ACCBF0DBDEFC62002592046637DE4/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402612442/FCAD38250C6AFB535AFC612F857933F268338A16/
>
> #### Location #2
>
> The second one is on a lone pillar. It's high up in the air and usually deserted when the road to it has been blown away.
>   It's easy to see. Though easy for Solarii to access with the far right
>   zip-line. You're extremely vulnerable when using said zip-line.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402621144/3950D32ACA91AADF8F5347BEC5600E199785491F/
>   http://cloud-3.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402625374/6AF24343AECFA623C9FB995961A210602F1A4BC5/
>
> #### Location #3
>
> The last one is on another pillar! This time it's the big one that enabled you to jump on top of the building. There's a
>   small outlet that seems to go nowhere, but the spawnpoint is at the
>   end.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402609645/8F46AB544B97DAF811543DCAC94851C2E9F1D4D8/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402612068/3D1D735E852139C7D5AF715A1E279B5EE8C16929/
>
> #### Additional map notes
>
> On the 2nd floor of the building, there's a door that can be opened for easier access. Lever is inside.
>
> Screenshots:
>   http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402613002/F09D147F015364B09604B2FEFB51F03EE14A9792/
>   http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/867214686402614268/0BFDDF6132B693701AD5987C44542F0FF6873D93/
>
> #### Monastery video
>
> I'll uphold the following rule in my videos:   Survivor's view first, then Solarii.
>   Loop from Location #1 to #3.

From "[TR Multiplayer - Superweapons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=133220679)" guide by [Xeno](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Xeforine/myworkshopfiles/?section=guides&appid=203160).

Considering the length of this answer, perhaps the question should be separated per map?

Comment: Oh my god, I don't care about formatting this properly anymore. I miss WYSIWYG.